# How to check which version of SQLite PDO use?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I used this code before I move to PDO:

```
    if (class_exists('SQLiteDatabase')) {
        return 'jargon.db';
    } else if (class_exists('SQLite3')) {
        return 'jargon3.db';
    } else {
        throw new Exception('SQLite not installed');
    }
```

How can I do the same using PDO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check SQLite version you can use following code:

```
$dbh = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
print_r("SQLite version " . $dbh->query('select sqlite_version()')->fetch()[0]);
$dbh = null;
```

Comment: I usually used to go to SQLite CLI to see the version. Now I am more educated. Good answer.

Comment: This will unnecessarily create a file called "test1.sqlite". Replace the first line with `$dbh = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');` to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 ways to get the sqlite version do it from the command line.

```bash
php -r "printf(\"%s\n\", (new PDO('sqlite::memory:'))->query('select sqlite_version()')->fetch()[0]);"
3.37.2

sqlite3 --version
3.37.2 2022-01-06 13:25:41 872ba256cbf61d9290b571c0e6d82a20c224ca3ad82971edc46b29818d5dalt1

php  -r "print_r(SQLite3::version());"
Array
(
    [versionString] => 3.37.2
    [versionNumber] => 3037002
)
```